# how to make an ajax request keep running even after I open different page

Tags: javascript, php, python, jquery, ajax

I am trying to request a php file(with python call inside the php file) using ajax call when I click a button in a form. As my php file takes too much time to execute i am opening a different page and performing some other actions while the ajax call completes.

if the python call executes properly... all the steps in php are executed even after i open different page(home page). but if the python fails all the corresponding steps which should be executed after the failed python call are not executed.(those steps are executed if  I stay at current page)..

// python call

```php
$para = array("x"=> $x,"y"=>$y,"z"=>$z);
$curl = curl_init($py_url); 
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$para);
$result = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);

if($result == '-1') 
{
perform some steps....
}
else 
{
continue with flow...
}
```

// Ajax call in view page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "http://localhost/pycurl.php",
            data: "x=1&y=2&z=3",
            success : function(result) { 
            }
        });
});
});
```

Comment: The AJAX call will not stop, you just will not see any return from it. That is why there is no continuation, you've moved away from the completion script.

Comment: What are you expecting to run? The PHP? The JavaScript?

Comment: i want the php to run completely

Comment: The PHP should also run completely, as long as you do not expect output to the browser.

Comment: Hey jay Thanks for response..After a lot time spent on debugging each line It seems there  was a step in a different program which was  restricting the code to proceed further..